# Integral double check.....

Tags: calculus

[image: find this integral]

I have the above integral I am trying to solve that I have taken the time to work out the steps below on paper and needed a couple of extra sets of eyes checking my work and the steps I have shown.  I am apologize for the chicken scratch and crudity! Thank you!

[image: worked out steps prior to sets of eyes!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct. The middle term should be $-\frac 1 {x^2}$.

You forgot to multiply by the 2 outside your integral.

Comment: Oops!  Thank you!  Exactly why I did this!  Its easy for me to miss a step!  They don't call me Captain Confused for nothing! :D

Comment: You're also missing $dx$ a couple of times... doesn't alter your answer but annoys the pedants! And the last lines begins with an $=$ symbol: what is on the left of that symbol?

Comment: Gotchya! I will make sure to address that.  :D